# CloudConnect data encoding validation

Tags: text, input, encoding, flat, gooddata

Hopefully, such functionality will be appreciated if it covers exclusion of invalid records by row from the input flat text files and only allowing the remaining rows from the input to pass through the process flow.

I thought ExtFilter component might work as so, but not certain yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected encoding is being set per file during CloudConnect project implementation. Either in the Reader component or in the metadata connected to the Reader component.